# Не устанавливается scm-manager

Tags: centos7

```
sudo yum install scm-server

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package scm-server.noarch 0:2.46.1- will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mercurial for package: scm-server-2.46.1-.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: java-17-openjdk-headless for package: scm-server-2.46.1-.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mercurial.x86_64 0:2.6.2-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package scm-server.noarch 0:2.46.1- will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-17-openjdk-headless for package: scm-server-2.46.1-.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: scm-server-2.46.1-.noarch (scm-manager)
           Requires: java-17-openjdk-headless
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Понимаю, что хочет "java-17-openjdk-headless". Но почему yum с собой не тянет openjdk как зависимость? Ну ладно, набираю

```
sudo yum install java-17-openjdk-headless
```

```
No package java-17-openjdk-headless available.
Error: Nothing to do
```